# Can the expression $6^{2n} - 25$ be a prime for all $n \geq 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Can the expression $6^{2n} - 25$ be a prime for any $n \geq 2$?

My attempt to solve the problem:

No, it cannot.
$6^{2n} - 25 = (6^{n})^{2} - 25 = (6^{n})^{2} - 5^{2} = (6^{n} + 5)(6^{n} - 5)$

And so the number will always be a product, thus it cannot be a prime.

Comment: Well done. Your solution is correct (a product of two numbers, each strictly greater than $1$)

Comment: @b00nheT Could you please post this as an answer? You can always make it community wiki if you don't want the rep...

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: Your opening question is slightly ambiguous (although the result renders the point moot) - it's not entirely clear whether the claim is that **all** such numbers are prime or **no** such numbers are prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done. Your solution is correct (a product of two numbers, each strictly greater than $1$)